# select value from a drop down list in IE - the value is selected but seems that the page did not register it -

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

I am trying to make a selection from the tax rate dropdown. The element is selected but the selection does not update the page. How do I get the selection to register?

**I am getting this:**

[image: Actual]

**I want this:**

[image: Desired]

---

I tried this :

```
ie.Document.getElementById("inv-taxrate-defaulter").selectedIndex = 7
ie.Document.getElementById("inv-taxrate-defaulter").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

And this:

```
Set tax = ie.getElementById("inv-taxrate-defaulter")
For i = 1 To tax.Options.Length
If tax.Options(i).Text = "FR 20" Then
tax.selectedindex = i
Exit For
End If
Next i
```

FYI : the value is selected (20 VAT) but seems that the page did not register it

---

HTML:

```html
<div id="inv-taxrate-defaulter-block">
                    Appliquer un taux de TVA à tous les articles
                    <select id="inv-taxrate-defaulter" autocomplete="off" data-dont-post="true">
                        <option value="" selected="">
                            Sélectionnez un taux de TVA
                        </option>
                                <option value="0.0">FR 0</option>
                                <option value="2.1">FR 2.1</option>
                                <option value="5.5">FR 5.5</option>
                                <option value="7.0">FR 7</option>                              
                                <option value="10.0">FR 10</option>
                                <option value="19.6">FR 19.6</option>
                                <option value="20.0">FR 20</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

---

**HTML Image:**

[image: HTML Image]

---

**Source HTML:**

[Link with source page HTML](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AGtksv-p7YkykBufrz814Zdoo8-wRUyV)

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't register it? Also, when you say it is selected you see the text change to selected for that option?

Comment: Did you try FireEvent with "onmousedown", "onmouseup" ?

Comment: Yes I did but the same issue

Comment: Try replicating the sequence i.e. combinations of mouseover ,keydown, click on the dropdown, keyup, keydown, make selection, key up, mouse out...

Comment: thank you for the advice I tried and I am not able to tip it in correct way - could you please be so kind and send to me the code ? to check were I did mistake by comparing both codes ? thank you and nice wekend

Comment: hello can somebody help/support ? thank you